# Integrating a ASP.NET (.aspx) page into a existing Lightswitch project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a aspx page developed in Visual Studio ASP and I want to integrate it into a Visual Studio LightSwitch existing project. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried to integrate it into Lightswitch, because if any changes were required I found it easier to leave it in its own Visual Studio project. I simply created a button and added a link to it (after I had uploaded it onto the IIS, for example:

```
window.open("IIS URL");
```

OR

```
window.open("IIS URL/Document.xls");
```

so if you don't find a way to do this, then hopefully this will help :)

Comment: ill look into it myself tomorrow and add it to the answer above if I get anywhere

Comment: thanks for accepting, still not looked into into it but when I do ill post it here